# Cancel an already executing task with Celery?

Tags: python, django, celery, message-passing

I have been reading the doc and searching but cannot seem to find a straight answer:

Can you cancel an already executing task? (as in the task has started, takes a while, and half way through it needs to be cancelled)

I found this from the doc at [Celery FAQ](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-cancel-the-execution-of-a-task)

```
>>> result = add.apply_async(args=[2, 2], countdown=120)
>>> result.revoke()
```

But I am unclear if this will cancel queued tasks or if it will kill a running process on a worker.  Thanks for any light you can shed!

Answer (score 242, accepted):

*revoke* cancels the task execution. If a task is revoked, the workers ignore the task and do not execute it. If you don't use persistent revokes your task can be executed after worker's restart.

https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#worker-persistent-revokes

revoke has an terminate option which is *False* by default. If you need to kill the executing task you need to set terminate to *True*.

```
>>> from celery.task.control import revoke
>>> revoke(task_id, terminate=True)
```

https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#revoke-revoking-tasks

Comment: Does this work in a distributed env? I mean if I have workers on multiple machines that are executing tasks. Does celery keep track of which machine the task is executing on?

Comment: It does. The communication with workers takes place via the broker.

Comment: result.revoke(terminate=True) should do the same thing as revoke(task_id, terminate=True)

Comment: Also, using the terminate option is "a last resort for administrators", as per recent Celery docs. You run the risk of terminating another task which has recently started on that worker.

Comment: unfortunately this works only on ampq and redis [doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html?highlight=revoke#std:control-revoke)

Comment: @Ja8zyjits Why does this only work on ampq and redis?

Comment: It doesn't work, 
```>>> from proj.celery import app <br>
>>> app.control.revoke(task_id)
```
This works only

Comment: From the command line, this worked like a charm using the hints from this answer.  I needed to stop some actively-executing tasks that were running way longer than desired: `celery -A <YOUR APP> inspect active | grep “<THE_TASK_YOU_WANT_TO_STOP>” | sed -e "s/.*id': '\([^']*\).*/\1/" | xargs celery -A <YOUR APP> control terminate KILL`

Comment: Have we ability to revoke and DELETE tasks  not from command prompt?

Answer (score 61):

In Celery 3.1, the [API of revoking tasks](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#revoke-revoking-tasks) is changed.

According to the [Celery FAQ](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-cancel-the-execution-of-a-task), you should use result.revoke:

```
>>> result = add.apply_async(args=[2, 2], countdown=120)
>>> result.revoke()
```

or if you only have the task id:

```
>>> from proj.celery import app
>>> app.control.revoke(task_id)
```

Answer (score 38):

@0x00mh's answer is correct, however recent celery [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#commands) say that using the `terminate` option is "*a last resort for administrators*" because you may accidentally terminate another task which started executing in the meantime. Possibly a better solution is combining `terminate=True` with `signal='SIGUSR1'` (which causes the SoftTimeLimitExceeded exception to be raised in the task).

Comment: This solution worked very well for me. When `SoftTimeLimitExceeded` is raised in my task, my custom cleanup logic (implemented via `try`/`except`/`finally`) is invoked. This is much better, in my view, than what `AbortableTask` offers (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.abortable.html). With the latter, you need a database result backend _and_ you have to manually and repeatedly check the status of an ongoing task to see if it's been aborted.

Comment: How is this better, as far I understand if there is any other task picked up by the process, its gonna be stopped anyway, just different exception will be thrown.

Comment: If I use `worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1` since I just have a few long running tasks the terminate should be fine - since no other tasks will be effected by terminating - did I get this correct? @spicyramen

Answer (score 8):

Per the 5.2.3 documentation, the following command can be run:

```
    celery.control.revoke(task_id, terminate=True, signal='SIGKILL')
```

where
`celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])`

Link to the doc: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.app.control.html?highlight=revoke#celery.app.control.Control.revoke

Answer (score 6):

You define celery app with broker and backend something like :

```
from celery import Celery
celeryapp = Celery('app', broker=redis_uri, backend=redis_uri)
```

When you run send task it return unique id for task:

```
task_id = celeryapp.send_task('run.send_email', queue = "demo")
```

To revoke task you need celery app and task id:

```
celeryapp.control.revoke(task_id, terminate=True)
```

Comment: the only answer works for me

Answer (score 5):

In addition, unsatisfactory, there is another way(abort task) to stop the task, but there are many unreliability, more details, see:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.abortable.html

Comment: This seems to be the best way to do it when using the 'threads' pool, as celery.control.revoke(task_id, terminate=True, signal='SIGKILL') does not work.

Answer (score 2):

```
from celery.app import default_app

revoked = default_app.control.revoke(task_id, terminated=True, signal='SIGKILL')
print(revoked)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please edit to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answer (score 1):

See the following options for tasks: [time_limit](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.time_limit), [soft_time_limit](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.soft_time_limit) (or you can set it for workers). If you want to control not only time of execution, then see [expires](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async) argument of apply_async method.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from celery.result import AsyncResult
task = AsyncResult(task_id)
task.revoke()
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?