# django celery terminate task's subprocesses

Tags: python, django, subprocess, task, celery

This is a follow-up question to my previous question:
[Cancel an already executing task with Celery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920643/cancel-an-already-executing-task-with-celery/8924116#8924116)

```
celery.task.control.revoke({task_id}, terminate=True)
```

does indeed kill my worker running the task.  I am now having the issue that my task is running subprocesses that do not die when the task is revoked.

This post by dmarkey
http://dmarkey.com/wordpress/2011/09/07/killing-child-processes-of-celery-tasks-on-a-timeout/
is the closest I've seen to what I want to do, except I don't want to kill on timeout, but rather when I revoke() with the task_id.

Seeming that all I have is the (String) task_id, is there anyway to kill such subprocesses?  Thanks for your help - I don't have quite as much experience with this as I'd like, navigating the docs is a challenge!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting a callback for [`on_revoked`](http://ask.github.com/celery/reference/celery.events.state.html?highlight=on_revoke#celery.events.state.Task.on_revoked) that kills the child processes of the task.

Comment: Is there a good way to get the pid(s) for running subprocesses?

Comment: Possibly, but I'm not aware of it. Maybe you could keep track of them when they are created? Edit: actually, the code in your link (by dmarkey) seems like it might work, or?