# End Celery worker task on, time limit, job stage or instruction from client

Tags: celery

I'm new to celery and I would appreciate a little help with a design pattern(or example code) for a worker I have yet to write.

Below is a description of the desired characteristics of the worker.

- The worker will run a task that collects data from an endless source, a generator.
- The worker task will run forever feeding from the generator unless it is directed to stop.

The worker task should stop gracefully on the occurrence of any one of the following triggers.

1. It exceeds an execution time limit in seconds.
2. It exceeds a number of iterations of the endless generator loop.
3. The client sends a message instructing the worker task to finish immediately.

Below is some sudo code for how I believe I need to handle trigger scenarios 1 and 2.

What I don't know is how I send the 'finish immediately' signal from the client and how it is received and executed in the worker task.

Any advice or sample code would be appreciated.

```
from celery.task import task
from celery.exceptions import SoftTimeLimitExceeded

COUNTLIMIT = # some value sent to the worker task by the client

@task()
def getData():
    try:
        for count, data in enumerate(endlessGeneratorThing()):
            # process data here
            if count > COUNTLIMIT: # Handle trigger scenario 2
                clean_up_task_nicely()
                break 
    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:  # Handle trigger scenario 1
            clean_up_task_nicely()
```

Comment: You can terminate executing task with revoke http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920643/cancel-an-already-executing-task-with-celery/8924116#8924116

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of revoke is that it only revokes a task prior to its execution.  For (3), I think what you want to do is use an AbortableTask, which provides a cooperative way to end a task:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.abortable.html

On the client end you are able to call task.abort(), on the task end, you are able to poll task.is_aborted()