# Django 1.9 + Celery unregistered tasks

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

> This configuration is **correct**. I was starting celery
>   the wrong way :(, without specifying the project name. (celery worker -A
>   hockey_manager -l info

I did upgrade to Django 1.9 from 1.6.5 and I can't make the celery configuration work again.

After almost two days of searching for a solution I didn't find anything working.

Celery doesn't detect my tasks. I tried with:

- CELERY_IMPORTS
- autodiscover_tasks
- bind=True

*Dependencies*

```
amqp==2.0.3 
celery==3.1.23 
Django==1.9.8 
django-celery==3.1.17
kombu==3.0.35
```

**PROJECT STRUCTURE**

[image]

**hockey_manager/__init__.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

**hockey_manager/celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'hockey_manager.settings.common')

app = Celery('hockey_manager')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

# load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks(['hockey'])

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
# app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
# app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

# Celery backend configs
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend',
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**hockey_manager/settings/common.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'hockey',
    'djcelery',
    'kombu.transport.django',
    ...
]

##
# Celery
##
# BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 3
BROKER_URL = os.environ.get('CLOUDAMQP_URL')
#BROKER_URL = 'django://'

# List of modules to import when celery starts.
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('hockey.tasks', )

#: Only add pickle to this list if your broker is secured
#: from unwanted access (see userguide/security.html)

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

**hockey/tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from hockey_manager.celery import app

@app.task(name='hockey.tasks.league_schedule_results')
def league_schedule_results(schedule, statistics):
    ...
```

*Error from Celery*

> [2016-07-23 17:05:46,231: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered
>   task of type 'hockey.tasks.league_schedule_results'.
>       The message has been ignored and discarded.

I also receive a deprecation warning from *amqp* starting from version 2.0:

> AMQPDeprecationWarning: The .transport attribute on the connection was
>   accessed before
>       the connection was established.  This is supported for now, but will
>       be deprecated in amqp 2.2.0.
>
> ```
> Since amqp 2.0 you have to explicitly call Connection.connect()
> before using the connection.
>
>   W_FORCE_CONNECT.format(attr=attr)))
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `django-celery` module.

here is [link](https://github.com/hirenalken/django-awesome-example/blob/master/django-celery-setup-steps.txt) to example how to use `django-celery` with django 1.9.1+

Comment: I'm already using it. It's showed in my dependencies list. Version 3.1.17

Comment: I am using it with django 1.9.1 and i dont need celery.py file for configuration. I just gave you suggestion to try steps mentioned in link. May be following that steps , you will configure celery correctly with django 1.9.1

Comment: I'll give a try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: I have no idea why, but it works :D. Thanks for the tip ;) Would be great to know the reason of this.

Comment: I'm feeling such an idiot :D. The configuration I have is correct. The problem is that I was starting celery with: celery worker -l info, instead of: celery -A hockey_manager worker -l info

Comment: I didn't use your suggested configuration because I didn't know how to access the Celery app to revoke a task. Any idea? ex: app.control.revoke(revoke_id, terminate=True)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920643/cancel-an-already-executing-task-with-celery