# Django How to stop the execution of a function

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am trying to call a python function by Ajax. I want to stop the execution of that function. I have tried to refresh the page but it doesn't stop. When I stopped the Django server then it get stop.

Here some code: This Call call HTTP request

```
class ScrapData():

    @classmethod
    def search_status(self, urls_list):
      for url in urls_list:
            r = requests.get(url)
            text = r.text
            #...

      return 1
```

Calling this view by Ajax

```
class SearchData(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        urls_list = [];
        response = ScrapData().search_status(urls_list)

        return HttpResponse(response)
```

I want to stop the function. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: self on classmethod?

Comment: What event is supposed to stop your function? Probably, you could set timeout for your request?

Comment: Sorry its mistake.. self will be cls

Comment: Like button click event. Or on page load, refresh

Answer (score 1):

How is this django app served? How many processes and threads? How do you know which thread runs the particular request? There are several Python ways to deal with this, but it is not as simple as "stop a particular request".

In my opinion, the best way to deal with long-polling tasks in terms of management, scaleability and self-sanity is to use some tool like Celery. There is also a dedicated [SO question on how to revoke a Celery task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920643/cancel-an-already-executing-task-with-celery).

Django Channels is another fresh approach to the matter, but it needs a bit of more development yet before it can be used rather than Celery.

Comment: thanks, is there any way to handle it by session, or through database etc?

Comment: Welcome. Sure, you deal with those within the view that is called when the cancel ajax is sent.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem that I called a a wrong and slow request. And I stopped it by restarting my Apache server. It might be a solution when it's ok to restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

try nested function, it will allow you to call whichever function you wish, or end process

the code:

```
class ScrapData():

    @classmethod
    def func():
        def search_status(self, urls_list):
              for url in urls_list:
                r = requests.get(url)
                text = r.text
                #...

          return 1
        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            urls_list = [];
            response = ScrapData().search_status(urls_list)

            return HttpResponse(response)
        def empty():
            pass
    #call the function you want to be excute further on
    #if you want nothing to happen then call empty function(pass keyword)
```

Comment: did this answer help? pls tell or at least accept