# resume running terminated task in celery upon worker restart

Tags: python, celery

After reading docs; what I understand is that you cannot rerun celery tasks outside of application contexts. 
Initially; what i thought was; terminated task would resume running once the worker has been restarted; however it didn't. I am currently using

```
celery.control.terminate(task_id)
```

That terminates my celery task id; I then tried running a worker with the same name hoping my revoked task would resume and finish; it didn't. After doing bit of research; I saw that a task can be *reran* with the same arguments; I thought MAYBE it would resume if I reran the same task again, it didn't. How can I revoke a task - then be able to re run it.

I'm using .apply_async() to intiate my task.

Answer (score 0):

Use revoke instead of terminate e.g:

```
celery_app.control.revoke(task_id)
```

you can refer this solution as well.

> [Cancel an already executing task with Celery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920643/cancel-an-already-executing-task-with-celery)