# How to cancel (terminate) a running task in celery? Already tried using "AsyncResult(task_id).revoke(terminate=True)", but it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

In the django project, I use celery to run asynchronous tasks. I want to implement a function to cancel the running task.

The official document[revoke: Revoking tasks](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#revoke-revoking-tasks) says that the "revoke(terminate=True)" method can be used. I tried it but it didn't work.
Here are some ways I've tried:

```py
...
task = AsyncResult("1e8fb3f3-4253-4bec-b71a-665ba5d23004")
print(task.state)
'STARTED'
task.revoke(terminate=True)
print(task.state)
'STARTED'
app.control.revoke("1e8fb3f3-4253-4bec-b71a-665ba5d23004", terminate=True)
print(task.state)
'STARTED'
```

And eventually it still executes to completion.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Or is there another way to achieve my needs in celery? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue in `Celery=5.3.0` and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25561389/7618968) helps me to resolve it. It says you should revoke tasks by their results, for example:

```
 result = add.apply_async(args=[2, 2], countdown=120)
 result.revoke()
```

Comment: @ Saeed Ramezani Thank you for your answer, I did use their results, like this: `from celery.result import AsyncResult`, but it doesn't work.