# How to cancel a HTMX request?

Tags: django, file-upload, htmx

I've this HTMX form which uploads image to the server. I want to add a cancel button which cancels the HTMX request.

HTML side of it:

```
            <form id="uploadForm" hx-post="{% url 'pins:upload_image' %}" hx-target="#imageUploadResponse"
                  hx-swap="outerHTML"
                  hx-on::before-request="removeResponseText(), showProgressBarCancelButton()"
                  hx-sync="closest form:drop"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                
                <!- REST OF THE CODE CAN BE IGNORED BECAUSE IRRELEVANT ->

                <footer class="modal-card-foot">
                    <button type="submit" class="button is-success" id="imageUpload">Upload</button>
                    <button id="abortUpload" onclick="abortHTMXUpload()"
                            class="button is-hidden">Cancel
                    </button>
                </footer>
            </form>
```

JS side of it:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.5"></script>

<script>
    const burgerToggle = document.querySelector(".navbar-burger");
    const navbarMenu = document.querySelector(".navbar-menu");
    const uploadButton = document.querySelector(".upload");
    const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
    const modalForm = document.getElementById("uploadForm");
    const progressBar = document.getElementById("progress");
    const abortUpload = document.getElementById("abortUpload");

    // Rest of the code can be ignored due to irrelevant from this topic

    htmx.on('#uploadForm', 'htmx:xhr:progress', function(evt) {
      htmx.find('#progress').setAttribute('value', evt.detail.loaded/evt.detail.total * 100)

    });

    function abortHTMXUpload() {
        htmx.trigger('#uploadForm','htmx:abort')

    }
</script>
```

I hope the code is self-explanatory.

I've gone through the HTMX docs, tried  `htmx:xhr:abort` and similar, nothing seems to work.

Comment: When you say `cancel the request` do you mean cancel the upload (lets say it takes 2 mins) with another request?

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible to cancel the previous not done request with another request. Unless the upload was processed by a celery queue, you can cancel the request based on this accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8924116

Comment: no not with another request. The file is uploading, I wanna cancel that.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the Cancel button with the [doc's](https://htmx.org/events/#htmx:abort) example.

```
<button id="abortUpload"
        onclick="htmx.trigger('#uploadForm', 'htmx:abort')"
        class="button is-hidden">Cancel
</button>
```

Or

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('uploadForm').dispatchEvent(new Event('htmx:abort'))">
  Cancel
</button>
```

Comment: Exactly, this is what I end up doing, can't have it in the separate js section.

Comment: Is it working then?